# How is this bound

Tags: python

I am writing my own class and methods and I have it all complete except the part of using `localtime()` to determine a user's age. I have never used `localtime()`. so I don't know how to implement it in the code. Currently, in the manner it's written, it returns a bound error.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Nov 15 22:10:07 2015

@author: Daddy
"""

class Person ():

    def __init__(self, name, birthyear):
        self.name = name
        self.birthyear = birthyear

    def age(self, birthyear):
        age = 2015 - self.birthyear
        return age

    def name(self):

        return self.name

class Instructor(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, birthyear, degree):
        self.name = name
        self.birthyear = birthyear
        self.degree = degree

    def degree(self, degree):

        return (self.degree)

class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, birthyear, major):
        self.name = name
        self.birthyear = birthyear
        self.major = major

    def major(self, major):

        return (self.major)
```

Comment: You're using `degree` and `major` as both an attribute and method.

Comment: I like your code, because it means I'll still be 33 years old in 2050 :)

Comment: Your major/degree/name methods all have binding conflicts in this code.  The methods are usually referred to as getters, and so should names like get_name, get_major, and get_degree.  They should not take any arguments besides self, as the field is known to self.  Your name method is a good example of what you should have in your major and degree methods.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
def age(self):
   return datetime.datetime.now().year - self.birthyear
```

Note you don't need to pass birthyear because it's in self, and return is the value of the called function.

Comment: This, plus fixing your major/degree methods should get you where you need to go.

Comment: you also should look at calling super to initialize your inherited functions